# how to get a product ID by accessing a product file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a file that is part of a product, I need to automate a file attribute (partnumber) that asks for a product attribute, how can I access this information?

My models.py:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    ...
    tipoProduto = ForeignKey(TipoProduto, ...)
    ...

class Arquivo(models.Model):
    revisao = IntegerField()
    nome = CharField(max_length=30)
    tipo = CharField(max_length=4, choices=tipoArquivo)
    tipoArquivo = CharField(max_length=15, choices=tipoArquivoSLD)
    partNumber = CharField(max_length=16, null=True, blank=True)
    tipoFabricacao = CharField(max_length=25, choices=tipoFabricacaoChoice)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=filePath)
```

my views.py:

```
def GetPartNumber(request, id):
    partnumberForm = PartNumberForm()
    file = Arquivo.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        partnumberForm = PartNumberForm(request.POST or None)
        if partnumberForm.is_valid():
            pt = partnumberForm.save(commit=False)
            productTip = 'GC'
            sldTip = file.tipoArquivo
            cod = PartNumber.objects.get()
            year = datetime.date.today().year
            pt = str(productTip) + str(sldTip) + str(cod) + '-' + str(year)
            pt.save()
    context={'partnumberForm':partnumberForm}
    return render(request, 'produtos/NewPartNumber.html', context)
```

Comment: What is your `PartNumber` model?

Comment: ```class PartNumber(models.Model):
    partNumber = CharField(max_length=30)
    terceiro = CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    
    dateCriacao = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    produto = ForeignKey(Produto, on_delete=CASCADE)```

Comment: put it in question - it will be more readable and more people wil see it.

Comment: not in my case, the item is related to the product, and i need the accurate information of this product. There are more product variables with the same name, and I can't pull the wrong item's information